# Debug Android WebViews in React Native

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I need to inspect the content and network requests of a webview I have running inside my app. With iOS I can open the simulator, open Safari, and am then able to inspect the webview as I would any other website.

I am having trouble with Android. I have gone to chrome://inspect, and am able to inspect Chrome on the connected device, however I am unable to inspect a webview.

I have tried moving `webView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);` inside ReactWebViewManager.java into the `onPageStarted` method so that it's always enabled, but this has had no effect.

Thanks

Comment: I am also having this issue. I must have read everything on the internet in this area but I can't find anything helpful. Perhaps it isn't possible?

Comment: @urbananimal I'm fairly sure it is possible, however I still haven't figured it out. Instead I installed Genymotion and it worked without any extra setup

Comment: I have no problem debugging in the emulator, it's on an actual physical device I'm having issues. This would be fine if it wasn't for the fact that the issue I'm trying to debug doesn't occur in either the standard Android emulator or Genymotion.

Comment: @urbananimal that sounds like a pain. If you figure it out be sure to post it as an answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

OK so we have this working now.

What we did in our app was that we call `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);` inside the `onCreate` method of our MainActivity.java (found at android/app/src/main/java/com/[appname]).

I'm not sure it has an `onCreate` method out of the box so you may have to add one or try it elsewhere - we must have read the same article as I had previously done as you had and moved the call into the onPageStarted method of ReactWebViewManager.java but that didn't work for me either.

setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled is a static method of android.webkit.WebView so just make sure you have that import.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Don't forget to `import android.webkit.WebView;` in your MainActivity.java. The method `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled`is static.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked for me too.

Comment: If I want to disable this by setting WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(false); i can still see application showing in chrom:inspect. Is there any change?